# Currency NumberFormatter - omit fraction part when the number is integer

Tags: ios, cocoa, number-formatting, foundation, nsnumberformatter

I need a specific behaviour from my NumberFormatter used to output currency:

- If the number is integer (0, 0.00) it should not show decimal separator (0 €)
- Else (123.90, 12.1), it should show two digits after decimal separator (123.90 €, 12.10 €).

The way I create and use my formatter now is the following:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencySymbol = "€"
formatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = false
let num = formatter.string(from: 123.9)!
```

If created like this, the formatter always shows decimal separator, despite the fact that I set this property to false.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you add the code where you are actually converting ?

Comment: As per your second point, if it is a decimal, it should be 123.90 €. In the input string you are passing 123.9. If you don't want decimal part for this, you are contradicting second point.

Comment: I want 123.9 OR 123.90 displayed as 123.90, and any integers without fraction part. Where is the contradiction? Or do you think 123.9 and 123.90 are different numbers internally when passed to the formatter?

Comment: It contradicts with - If created like this, the formatter would always show decimal separator, despite the fact that I set this property to false.
Why are you using alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator ?

Comment: I don't want to show decimal separator at all times – only when there is actually something significant in the fraction part. Apparently, you're trying to say that it is not what alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator is designed for.

Comment: Not at all clear. Let me try one last time : As per your last statement - **If created like this, the formatter would always show decimal separator, despite the fact that I set this property to false.** So by that you mean, you want to display 123.9 as **123 €**. But as per your second point requirement - **Else (123.90, 12.1), it should show two digits after decimal separator (123.90 €, 12.10 €)**. As you can see, both these contradict with each other.

Comment: No, by my first statement I described the reality (**the formatter would always show decimal separator**) against my expectation (**I set this property to false** - meaning, I only want to show it when there is something significant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currency `numberStyle` is always returning decimal point followed two digits. So if you want to achieve your goal, you should modify the output string by yourself.

Please check the example code:

```
    let number1: Double = 123.908392857
    let number2: Int = 123
    let number3: Float = 123.00

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.currencySymbol = "€"
    let num1 = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number1))! // Output €123.91
    let num2 = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number2))! // Output €123.00
    let num3 = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number3))! // Output €123.00

    print("\(num1) \(num2) \(num3)")

    // This is trick
    let newNum1 = trimString(string: num1) // Output €123.91
    let newNum2 = trimString(string: num2) // Output €123
    let newNum3 = trimString(string: num3) // Output €123

    print("\(newNum1) \(newNum2) \(newNum3)")
```

`trimString` is a simple trim function, you can put it in the `String extension` or any place you want.

```
func trimString(string: String) -> String {
    if string.hasSuffix(".00") {
        return String(string.dropLast(3))
    }
    else {
        return string
    }
}
```

You may have question about why `alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator` is not working then? It is for `.decimal` `numberStyle` and default `decimalSeparator` is "."

Comment: And what about "123,00 ₽"